# Customer community license API limits

Tags: api, customer-community, limits, licenses

Our clients want to use our managed package Lightning aura component to view some records. That component has a button like PAY NOW or DOWNLOAD or CANCEL which involves an API call to external system. Lot of clients are using CUSTOMER COMMUNITY LICENSE. But, as per the [Documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=users_license_types_communities.htm&type=5) "API Calls per Day (by Org)" is 0(Zero) for Customer Community License.Does this mean community users can not make any API calls and will not be able to CANCEL or PAY an Invoice from Community portal?

Do we have any workarounds in this situation or do we need to ask the client to upgrade the license to any of PLUS licenses? Please advice. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The published API limit is for the Salesforce API, not other external APIs.  We have Customer Community licenses that are able to exercise Apex controllers that make callouts to external APIs just fine.

There are other gotchas though.  The basic Customer Community user can't use the base CRM objects (Lead, Opportunity, etc), reports, dashboards, or files.

Comment: Salesforce API means inbound APIs to SF from external system?

Comment: You said API call TO an external system.  If the API call is FROM an external system, that's a different matter, and much less common.  It sounds like the documentation says this is not supported with the basic customer community license.  Instead, have the external system call into SF using an admin or other user context.